# AngularJs orderBy working on date as string

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, sql-order-by, firebase

AngularJs orderBy treats date as string. I want to get the order by as numeric values on date because it compares first date, then month and then year. My json data is below:

```
"simplelogin:23" : {
          "chatdiscussion" : "He",
          "nextstep" : "The",
          "sessiondate" : "7 January 2015 +0530",
          "studentemail" : "damchoe.pem1234@gmail.com",
          "studentname" : "Damchoe"
          },
```

Now I want that the data with latest date comes first but it first filters the date then month then year working as a string 
please help me get out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter on a string like "7 January 2015 +0530" ...

You'll have to either :

- return a more standard/filterable date format in your JSON feed, like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss"
- convert your JSON date to something filterable (you can try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for that)